# How to put item in dynamodb on the fly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Below code will help to put the data in dynamodb

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('employees')
table.put_item(Item={
    'emp_id': '2',
    'name': 'kammana',
    'salary': 20000
})
```

I want to put_item below details on press on `test` button i need to pass

```
{'emp_id': '2', 'name': 'kammana', 'salary': 20000}
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams No error instead of passing through the code i need to pass as input  to lambda handler

Comment: Are you using the `event` paramenter that gets passed in by default to the lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your lambda handler. Pass your dictionary as event. Make sure you configure your `template.yaml` and `API gateway` as well. You can find more on the `docs` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html).

`app.py`

```py
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('employees')

#PASS THIS AS EVENT THROUGH API GATEWAY: {'emp_id': '2', 'name': 'kammana', 'salary': 20000} 

def handler(event,context):
    table.put_item(Item=event)
```